# Update html after change in select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with current version of html in html() method in jQuery. 
I sent ajax that return me value then I must update text in span and value in select and in the end sent a html to fnUpdate in Datatables.

```
success: function (data) {
    var td = $('[data-id="question-status-' + id + '"]');
    td.find('.status-value').text('status: ' + data);
    td.find('select').val(data);
    oTable.fnUpdate(td.html(), index, 5);
}
```

After update I see `status:` with new value, but in the select I see old value. Where is bug? Am I updating  the DOM wrong?

Comment: Does data already exists in select option values?

Comment: I think you have to do `td.find('select option[value="'+data+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected')` instead of `td.find('select').val(data)`

Comment: something about `.draw`

Comment: @Azim - Yes, you're right. But works only when: `td.find('select option').removeAttr('selected');` and `td.find('select option[value="' + data + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');` Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the solution provided by @Azim in the comments, but assuming that data is the same as the value of the option, you need to trigger a change to get the updated value set as the currently selected option:

```
td.find('select').val(data).change();
```

Comment: I forget about one more important information. I have event on this selector. When you change this selector, runs is ajax and then change span and update row in datatables. So this method change () loop all,  because it starts again. Maybe more code would explain it...